# Ffmpeg is vertically flipping a video that doesn't have rotate in the metadata and the ffmpeg command does not have transpose

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that plays fine in Quicktime.  When run through FFMPEG, ffmpeg is flipping it vertically.  However, my command does not include a flip command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg     -safe 0 -f concat -i  concat.txt    -i videogettingflipped.MOV         
-filter_complex "[1]scale=1280:-2,pad=1280:1280:0:280[1v];[1v][0]overlay=0:0 "  
-aspect 1:1  -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -level 3.1  
-map 1:a  -c:a aac -b:a 128k      -r 30    -y  finalvideo.mp4
```

Here is the JSON from ffprobe and rotation says 0 which I assume is no rotation.  Is there something else in this data that is telling FFMPEG to flip this video?

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/44100",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/44100",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 10168505,
            "duration": "230.578345",
            "bit_rate": "200216",
            "max_bit_rate": "192000",
            "nb_frames": "9933",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "rotate": "0",
                "creation_time": "2020-03-25T02:06:14.000000Z",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "Core Media Audio"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "138347/8300400",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 720,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 31,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "4150200/138347",
            "time_base": "1/600",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 138347,
            "duration": "230.578333",
            "bit_rate": "2518518",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "6917",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "rotate": "0",
                "creation_time": "2020-03-25T02:06:14.000000Z",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "Core Media Video",
                "encoder": "H.264"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Display Matrix",
                    "displaymatrix": "\n00000000:        65536           0           0\n00000001:            0      -65536           0\n00000002:            0    47185920  1073741824\n",
                    "rotation": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "video.MOV",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "230.578333",
        "size": "78501353",
        "bit_rate": "2723633",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "qt  ",
            "minor_version": "0",
            "compatible_brands": "qt  ",
            "creation_time": "2020-03-25T02:06:14.000000Z",
            "com.apple.quicktime.make": "Apple",
            "com.apple.quicktime.model": "iPhone 11",
            "com.apple.quicktime.software": "13.3.1",
            "com.apple.quicktime.creationdate": "2020-03-17T15:06:47-0400"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that I know anything about ffmpg, but if it's from a phone are you certain it's not UN-flipping it; recorded on the front camera?

Comment: Well generally, even then I would think you would see some kind of rotate command in the metadata?  When I play the original video in Quicktime, however, it is fine.  It isn't flipped there.

Comment: ok, was just a guess. Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new API for orientation is the displaymatrix side data. You can add `-noautorotate` before `-i videogettingflipped.MOV` to suppress any correction.